# Strapi V4 how to modify data response for a component (dynamic zone)

Tags: strapi

Imagine a case where an editor adds a “Latest Products” component to a page using dynamic zone: they add a title, a summary, and then the latest products will automatically be fetched to be available in the response. How can I add this data to the response of the component?

I know we can override the response for content types using a [custom controller](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/controllers.html#implementation), but I can't find anything for how to modify the response for a component.

Maybe there's an alternative approach I haven't thought of, but coming from a Drupal preprocess-everything background this is all I can think of.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: i want to do the same thing, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Kardon63 I've just posted what I did below. There's probably a better way but it's the best I could do at the moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't the best way, but I created a service for components that can be used in the content type controller to modify the response. Any improvements appreciated!

/api/custom-page/controllers/custom-page.js

```
'use strict';

/**
*  custom-page controller
*/

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::custom-page.custom-page', ({ strapi }) =>  ({

async find(ctx) {

const componentService = strapi.service('api::components.components');

let { data, meta } = await super.find(ctx);


data = await Promise.all(data.map(async (entry, index) => {

  if(entry.attributes.sections){
    await Promise.all(entry.attributes.sections.map(async (section, index) => {
      const component = await componentService.getComponent(section);
      entry.attributes.sections[index] = component;
    }));
  }
  return entry;

}));


return { data, meta };
},

}));
```

/components/services/components.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * components service.
 */

module.exports = () => ({
  getComponent: async (input) => {

    // Latest products
    if(input.__component === 'sections.latest-products'){
      input.products = 'customdatahere';
    }

    return input;

  }
});
```